# django admin foreign key default value inline

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-keys, inline, django-grappelli

I'm converting an ancient Client/Server app (Delphi) into a Django app for a small brick and morter bookstore (wife's).

Since most functions are admin, I'm using the Django admin interface with grappelli for some easier lookups.

I have 3 models: Book, Sale and Item.

```
class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Books are described individually and are related to collections
    as many to many. Every book in this system is unique - i.e. there are 
    not quantity fields. This is optimized for used book stores where book
    condition is essential.
    """

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
                        ('IN STOCK', 'IN STOCK'), 
                        ('SOLD', 'SOLD'),
                        ('ON LOAN', 'ON LOAN'),
                        ('HOLD', 'HOLD'),
                     )

    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, db_index=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2, default=0)
    description = models.TextField()

    collections = models.ManyToManyField(Collection)

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ["author", "title"],
            ["status", "title", "author"],
        ]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s [%d] - %s - $%.2f" % (self.title, self.id, self.book_type, self.sell_price)

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_queryset():
        instock = Book.objects.filter(status="IN STOCK")
        return instock    

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return("id__iexact", "title__istartswith",)

class Sale(TimeStampedModel):
    """ 
    Sales group all sold items which may or may not be books and are sold to contacts.  
    We use a "generic" contact of "cash" for non named contacts 
    """ 
    PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES =  ( ('Cash', 'Cash'), ('Charge', 'Charge'), ('Check', 'Check'))

    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True)
    sale_date = models.DateField(blank=True,default=datetime.date.today, db_index=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    taxed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tax_exempt_no = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    sales_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    amt_tender = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    pct_discount = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amt_credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    amt_shipping = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    amt_due = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    tot_sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    tot_items = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    ordering = ['-sale_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.sale_date)

class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Items are usually books sold on a sale. Items can also be entered manually
    at time of sale if they are not books from inventory
    """
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, blank=True)
    item_desc = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_desc
```

For the Sale form, I use an admin form with Tabular inline Items. Items are usually books (via a foreign key lookup), but can also be entered manually for non-inventory items so I have a sell_price both in the book model and in the item model.

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    raw_id_fields = ("book",)
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'fk': ['book'],
    }
    extra = 2
```

What I'd like to do in the foreign key lookup is to return the key of the book AND fill in the Item's sellprice with the sellprice from the book I looked up.

I have the basic lookup working just fine but can't find out how to set the item sellprice to the book's sellprice immediately after the lookup.

Any advice is appreciated! I have tried figuring out the objects to put some JS logic in but the inlines get object ids created dynamically, I think. I'm no JS expert.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post so that we can help you.

Comment: Updated with source code. I simplified it a bit. Still struggling with this one.